# How to check if `sympy.dsolve` can solve differential equation in explicit form?

Tags: python, sympy, dsolve

I'm testing `dsolve` method of `sympy` package in order to check if any differential can be solved and return solution if it is. Trying to solve equation of this kind

```
from sympy import dsolve
t = symbols('t')
x = Function('x')
dsolve(x(t).diff(t) - x(t)**2 + t**2)
```

returns an answer:

[image]

The last term of this expression tells me that an equation doesn't have explicit solution. How can I check if equation has an explicit solution using `sympy`?

I hope something like this:

`is_solution_explicit(x(t).diff(t) - x(t)**2 + t**2)` returns `False`
`is_solution_explicit(2*x(t)/(1+t) + (1+t)**3)` returns `True`

Comment: This particular example is a series solution from the series solver. There should be a way to disable these: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15916
You can check for it with `sol.has(O)`

Comment: @Oscar Thanks a lot for this link. I have at least one working solution now :)